# Getting following error while making .deb pacakage using checkinstall

Tags: checkinstall

I am using checkinstall to prepare debian package in my ubuntu machine. I did following procedure to prepare it

```
 source_file_directory/ make 
 checkinstall -D make install
```

I got following at the end.

```
   Installing with make...Installing with install...

   ========================= Installation results ===========================
   make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

   ****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

   Cleaning up...OK

   Bye.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you do the ./configure before the make? There should be a readme file with instructions to configure/compile/install the package.

You do not need to specify the 'make install' as that is the default.

Comment: i don't have any configure directory in my source code. What can i do in that case?

Comment: Is the debian package destined to be distributed because in that case you cannot use checkinstall. Checkinstall purpose is to cleanly uninstall the program afterwards using the standard tools. For creating debian packages to be distributed you must follow the instructions in the Packaging Guide : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete . This is not too bad as there are good tools to help here.